# Generating PDF from 'qute' HTML template in Quarkus: any alternatives to flying-saucer-pdf?

Tags: quarkus

is there a way to generate pdf from an html generated with "qute" templating ? (Works in native mode)

My point is that I use flying-saucer-pdf but it seems incompatible with native build. ITextRenderer throw an exception in graalvm : "Discovered unresolved method during parsing: org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxBuilder.createRootBox".

Answer (score 3):

I'm using openhtmltopdf:

```
String result = transformersPDF.data("equipments", infoList, "filters", filterList).render();
PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
builder.useFastMode();
builder.withHtmlContent(result, imagePath);
builder.toStream(baos);
```

transformersPDF is injected

```
@Inject
Template transformersPDF;
```

It works fine, but now I'm facing issues in kubernetes environment:
Images are not being rendered even when worked locally.

Hope it helps
(I'm in a hurry, sorry I can't elaborate further)